# Can't boot Windows after installing Kali Linux?

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, partitioning, grub

I recently tried installing Kali Linux on HP notebook, but during this the installation of grub failed.

Now on rebooting I get the message "`No boot-able device found please insert boot-able device and press enter`". So to fix this I installed Kali Linux again. This it installed correctly with grub.

But now on restarting I only see Kali Linux as an option to boot, no Windows. My partitions on gparted look like this

[image]

I can't even load my HP recovery partion. It gives the same message "`No boot-able device found please insert boot-able device and press enter`"

Can anyone help me to at least run my HP System Recovery?

Answer (score 1):

Execute
`sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom`
, then add this:

```
menuentry "Windows 8" {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='(hd0,msdos4)'
chainloader +1
}
```

And execute `sudo update-grub`

Should work, I think.